# mongo-ruby-driver will not create a new document on upsert when there is a custom _id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I want to upsert a document with the mongo-ruby-driver using something like the following-

```
id = "#{params[:id]}:#{Time.now.strftime("%y%m%d")}"
# db.collection('metrics').insert({'_id' => id})
db.collection('metrics').update(
  { '_id' => id },
  { '$inc' => { "hits" => 1 } },
  { 'upsert' => true }
)
```

Right now this will only update existing documents, and not create one if it doesn't already exist. The only way it will perform both actions is if I uncomment the insert() command above it.

If I use the mongo console and try and do this upsert directly (without the need for the insert() ) it works as expected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use a symbol instead of string in params. This code works.

```
db.collection('metrics').update(
  { '_id' => id },
  { '$inc' => { "hits" => 1 } },
  { :upsert => true }
)
```

In fact, you can use symbols most everywhere. This also works:

```
db.collection(:metrics).update(
  { :_id => id },
  { :$inc => { :hits => 1 } },
  { :upsert => true }
)
```